# 'future' has been explicitly marked deleted here

Tags: c++, macos, asynchronous, future

I am trying to build a Async application to allow processing of large lists in parallel, and after two days of learning C++ through googling I have come up with the title error, from the following code:

```
//
//  main.cpp
//  ThreadedLearning
//
//  Created by Andy Kirk on 19/01/2016.
//  Copyright © 2016 Andy Kirk. All rights reserved.
//

#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>
#include <future>

typedef struct {
    long    mailing_id;
    char    emailAddress[100];
} emailStruct ;

typedef struct {
    long    mailing_id = 0;
    int     result = 0;
} returnValues;

returnValues work(emailStruct eMail) {

    returnValues result;

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(2));

    result.mailing_id = eMail.mailing_id;

    return result;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    std::vector<emailStruct>    Emails;
    emailStruct eMail;

    // Create a Dummy Structure Vector
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 100 ; ++i) {
        std::snprintf(eMail.emailAddress,sizeof(eMail.emailAddress),"user-%d@email_domain.tld",i);
        eMail.mailing_id = i;
        Emails.push_back(eMail);
    }


    std::vector<std::future<returnValues>> workers;

    int worker_count = 0;
    int max_workers  = 11;


    for ( ; worker_count < Emails.size(); worker_count += max_workers ){

        workers.clear();

        for (int inner_count = 0 ; inner_count < max_workers ; ++inner_count) {
            int entry = worker_count + inner_count;
            if(entry < Emails.size()) {
                emailStruct workItem = Emails[entry];
                auto fut = std::async(&work, workItem);
                workers.push_back(fut);
            }
        }

        std::for_each(workers.begin(), workers.end(), [](std::future<returnValues> & res) {
            res.get();
        });

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Really not sure what I am doing wrong, and have found limited answers searching.  Its on OSX 10 if that is relevant, and XCode 7.

Answer (score 8):

The `future` class has its [copy constructor deleted](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future/future), because you *really* don't want to have multiple copies of it.

To add it to the vector, you have to move it instead of copying it:

```
workers.push_back(std::move(fut));
```

Answer (score 0):

This error can also be raised if you are passing a future object (within a thread) to a function which expects a pass by value.

For example, this would raise an error when you pass the future:

```
void multiplyForever(int x, int y, std::future<void> exit_future);

multiplyForever(3, 5, fut);
```

You can fix it by passing the future by reference:

```
void multiplyForever(int x, int y, std::future<void>& exit_future);

multiplyForever(3, 5, fut);
```